# What is "mtr --report --tcp --port=22" telling me?

Tags: firewall, port, traceroute

RHEL 8.4

Here's the output of `mtr` to a server for which the firewall is open to port 22:

```
$ mtr --report --tcp --port=22 --no-dns Server1
Start: 2023-08-09T21:49:20-0400
HOST: foo.example.com        Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 10.a.b.c           0.0%    10    0.5   0.5   0.5   0.7   0.1
  2.|-- 10.d.e.f           0.0%    10    1.1   1.2   1.1   1.5   0.2
  3.|-- 10.g.h.i           0.0%    10    1.0   0.9   0.8   1.0   0.1
  4.|-- j.k.l.m            0.0%    10    1.0   1.0   0.8   1.2   0.1
  5.|-- 10.n.o.p           0.0%    10    1.1   1.2   1.0   2.3   0.4
$
```

That's just what I expect.

But here's the "output" when running against a server where port 22 is blocked:

```
$ mtr --tcp --port=22 Server2
$
```

(Normal `mtr --report --no-dns Server2` shows me what I expect.)

Does that mean port 22 is blocked at the gateway (10.a.b.c), or am I misreading it?